# How to check multiple checkbox options by default?

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox

I need to have the options "Twitter, Facebook and Google Plus" selected by default. Here's the part of the code :

```
function setup_settings()
{        
    $this->boxes = array(
        'ch_box_settings' => array(
            'title' => __('Widget Settings', 'contesthopper'),
            'fields' => array(
                'ch_social' => array(
                    'id' => 'ch_social',
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    'title' => __('Social buttons', 'contesthopper'),
                    'description' => __('Select the checkboxes above to display social share buttons after you capture an email.', 'contesthopper'),
                    'options' => array(
                        'twitter' => 'Twitter',
                        'facebook' => 'Facebook',
                        'googleplus' => 'Google+',
                        'linkedin' => 'LinkedIn',
                        'pinit' => 'Pinterest'
                    ),
                    'conditional' => array(
                        'twitter' => 'ch_box_twitter',
                        'facebook' => 'ch_box_facebook',
                        'linkedin' => 'ch_box_linkedin',
                        'pinit' => 'ch_box_pinit'
                    )
                ),
```

Plugin used: [ContestHopper for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contesthopper/)

([Github source](https://github.com/Webikon/ContestHopper/blob/master/pages/page-contest.php#L2104-L2129))

Comment: If you have this working on a webpage, right click the widget and select inspect element. If the checkboxes have an ID or the container has an ID you can use javascript to target all checkbox elements within that element. I'm going to take a guess and say ch_social = the container and ch_box_twitter is either the container for that box or the id of the element.

Comment: Have you tried/Can you use javascript?